# Weight Painting Won't Get Rid of Weird Protrusions

Tags: weight-painting

I tried adding weight, removing weight and removing doubles. The mesh popping out won't go away.
Any ideas?

[image]

Blend File: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trouble shoot, enable *Adjust edit cage to modifier result* of the Armature modifier.

[image]

Then you can select the problem vertices in edit mode and examine the problem vertices.

[image]

This vertice should not be assigned to the *chest*. It should be mainly assigned to the *UpperArm.R*, currently it isn't.

To fix this go into weight paint mode, select the upper arm bone and add weight to the vertice.

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand 'Adjust edit cage modifier', but I edited the weights on the vertices and it's working better now than spraying the weight on was